# Adding a panel container to a PreferencePage in an Eclipse PDE project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I'm using the `FieldEditorPreferencePage` class in order to create a preferences page for my Eclipse plug-in. I've been able to add all the controls I need to the page, however there are several controls that I'd like to group together using a panel.

Here's an example from Eclipse's documentation. However, there's no information about how the "Open mode" panel was added to the page, and how controls were added to it.

How do I add a panel to an Eclipse `PreferencePage`?

[image]

Comment: You can do a group of radio buttons on a field editor preference page but I think it would be a struggle to do the enabled/disabled check boxes as well. The particular preference page you show just extends `PreferencePage` and creates normal SWT controls rather than using field editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own `GroupFieldEditor` class, based on two implementations I found that didn't exactly meet my requirements. `FieldEditor`s can be added to that control, and the group can then be added to a `FieldEditorPreferencePage` object using the `addField()` method.

The implementation is available [**here**](https://github.com/SpartanRefactoring/spartan-refactoring/blob/master/SpartanRefactoring/src/main/java/il/org/spartan/refactoring/preferences/GroupFieldEditor.java)

For example, this is how the group looks in my plug-in project:

[image]

Comment: The link for the GroupFieldEditor implementation on your comment "The implementation is available here" is broken. Could you update the link or share your implementation so we can have a look the way you solved the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A brief steps for adding a preferencePage:

1. open plugin.xml and go to **Extension** tab.
2. Add extension point `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages`
3. Specify id/name and other attributes.
4. Implement class extend from `PreferencePage`.

If you want to group several controls in a panel and use it in `FieldEditorPreferencePage`, you can create new class extended from `org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor`. For example:

```
public class MyFieldEditor extends FieldEditor {
    public MyFieldEditor(String name, String labelText, Composite parent) {
        super(name, labelText, parent);
    }

    protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {
        //...add your controls to panel
        Group grpOpenMode = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
        grpOpenMode.setText("Open mode");
        grpOpenMode.setBounds(10, 10, 230, 117);

        btnDoubleClick = new Button(grpOpenMode, SWT.RADIO);
        btnDoubleClick.setBounds(10, 21, 90, 16);
        btnDoubleClick.setText("Double click");

        btnSingleClick = new Button(grpOpenMode, SWT.RADIO);
        btnSingleClick.setBounds(10, 43, 90, 16);
        btnSingleClick.setText("Single Click");

        Button btnSelectOnHover = new Button(grpOpenMode, SWT.CHECK);
        btnSelectOnHover.setBounds(20, 63, 123, 16);
        btnSelectOnHover.setText("Select on hover");

        Button btnOpenUsingArrowKey = new Button(grpOpenMode, SWT.CHECK);
        btnOpenUsingArrowKey.setBounds(20, 85, 188, 16);
        btnOpenUsingArrowKey.setText("Open when using arrow keys");
    }

    protected void doLoad() {
        // get preference value, and set data to UI, Invoked after doFillIntoGrid(...)
        String prefix = getPreferenceName();
        boolean isDoubleClick = getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(prefix+"_isDoubleClick");
        btnDoubleClick.setSelection(isDoubleClick);
        btnSingleClick.setSelection(!isDoubleClick);
        btnSelectOnHoverget.setSelection(getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(prefix+"_selectOnHover");
    }

    protected void doLoadDefault() {
        //Invoked in preferencePages.performDefaults() - user click "Restore Default" button
    }

    protected void doStore() {
        //save data of UI to preference store. Invoked in preferencePages.performOk() - user click "OK"/"Apply" button
        getPreferenceStore().setValue(getPreferenceName()+"_isDoubleClick",btnDoubleClick.getSelection());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it's not comprehensive enough to answer my specific question

Comment: I edit the answer.Please check it. Actually, if the *Panel* only used once. I prefer to implement class extend from <code>PreferencePage</code>.
Just like the "Open mode" panel. I think it's created by **protected void createOpenModeGroup(Composite composite)**. The source code is in org.eclipse.ui.ide.source_???.jar\org\eclipse\ui\internal\dialogs\WorkbenchPreferencePage.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RadioGroupFieldEditor` to add a set of radio buttons surrounded by a Group control.

Something like:

```
RadioGroupFieldEditor groupPref = new RadioGroupFieldEditor("preference key",
      "Group title message", 3, 
      new String[][] {
        {"radio 1 text", "preference value 1"}, 
        {"radio 2 text", "preference value 2"}, 
        {"radio 3 text", "preference value 3"}},
     getFieldEditorParent(), true /* use a group */);
addField(groupPref);
```

Comment: My fields are not radio buttons